# Visual Studio Custom Solution Configuration and Debug.Print

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, configuration, customization, visual-studio-debugging

I've created a new solution configuration in Visual Studio named "**QA**", copying its settings from "**Debug**".

After switching to the new "**QA**" configuration, statements in my VB code such as **Debug.Print**, **My.Application.Log.WriteEntry** and **My.Log.WriteEntry** no longer output any data.

I have as of writing this still have not found a solution. Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: While admit experiance is a little light, Debug messaging is for Debugging.  QA I would expect is more akin to release.  My.Application.Log.WriteEntry and My.Log.WriteEntry are likely a little different, worth noting that My.Application.Log.WriteEntry is for WinForms (and the like) while My.Log.WriteEntry is for Web Apps.  So I would expect only one of them to work anyway.  Perhaps you could update your question with some examples of your usage?

Comment: Can you confirm that the `DEBUG` conditional compilation constant is declared for that configuration?

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that my Visual Studio installation had been corrupted at some point. After performing a repair all seems to be working.